# Efficient way to handle user roles

Tags: mysql, database, theory, roles

I am working on one portal where will be few user roles. I have been wondering what is the best way to handle them. I have created separated tables for users and clients, but clients will want the functionality as users and users can become clients easy too.

I also don't want to make many joints, so what I as thinking is this:

I will have 4 different user roles (at least for now) as follow:

```
user
client
reviewer
admin
```

I will assing "id" to each role. At the same time I will keep table in mysql with these roles. It will be something like:

```
1 - admin
2 - reviewer
3 - client
4 - user
```

This table will be used only upon creation of user, to get the code of user "permissions". So Let's say that there will be a guy who is a user and reviewer. His role would be 24.

```
login  password  email role     created
----------------------------------------------------------
guy    password  guy@gmail.com  24 2012-12-08 23:12:30
```

I think this could work pretty well, but still want to ask if you guys think this is good and effective solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The other way to do this would be to have a many to many USER_ROLE table where for your example guy would have the following entires.

```
login role
guy   2
guy   4
```

I generally prefer this method of tracking roles. A join against this table in a situation like this should be fast and painless, especially if you move to using a user_id instead of a login, and index appropriately.

Comment: Of course there would be user_id, i just wrote it fast for example. I was thinking about this too, but still dont really like that join there.

Answer (score 0):

What you're defining is a Role Based Access Control System (I would suggest looking up resources on this). An RBAC system will have a separate table for users and another table for roles. There will be a many to many relationship between users and roles. Also, you will connect a permissions table to roles in another many to many relationship. The image attached represents how to implement this system:[RBAC SYSTEM IN MYSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zodpy.png)

A similar question was asked before: [How to design a hierarchical role based access control system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139712/how-to-design-a-hierarchical-role-based-access-control-system)