# How to design a hierarchical role based access control system

Tags: php, mysql, permissions, hierarchy, rbac

Basic deal is, we have a custom built "kickstart" for our projects. For this we are looking at redoing the user control. I know there are a lot of questions out there about general rbac, but I cannot find any on hierarchical rbac?

Our requirements are:

- Roles can be assigned to group permissions
- If the role does not have a permission entry then it is automatically denied
- A user can be given overriding permissions
- A users overriding permissions is either a grant or deny
- If a user is explicitly denied a permission no matter what roles say "granted" the override wins.
- Users can have multiple roles
- Roles can have hierarchy
- Roles can inherit from other roles (e.g. A "Forum Super Moderator" role is a "Forum Moderator", and a "System Maintainer", and the "Forum Moderator" role already inherits from the "Forum User" role )
- Roles that inherit from another role that deny or grant a privilege override their child permission
- Permissions are grouped by "module" (e.g. a "Blog" module can have an "edit entry" permission, and a "Forum" module can have an "edit entry" permission and they will not clash)
- There is a "Everything and Anything" permission that automatically grants full access

So, with those requirements out of the way, here's how I am thinking of doing it.

#### Table: Users

```
id            | int     | unique id
```

#### Table: Roles

```
id            | int     | unique id
--------------|---------------------------------------------
title         | varchar | human readable name
```

#### Table: Permissions

```
id            | int     | unique id
--------------|---------------------------------------------
module        | varchar | module name
--------------|---------------------------------------------
title         | varchar | human readable name
--------------|---------------------------------------------
key           | varchar | key name used in functions
```

#### Table: Role_User

```
role_id       | int     | id from roles table
--------------|---------------------------------------------
user_id       | int     | id from users table
```

#### Table: Permission_Role

```
id            | int     | unique id
--------------|---------------------------------------------
permission_id | int     | id from permissions table
--------------|---------------------------------------------
role_id       | int     | id from roles table
--------------|---------------------------------------------
grant         | tinyint | 0 = deny, 1 = grant
```

#### Table: Permission_User

```
id            | int     | unique id
--------------|---------------------------------------------
permission_id | int     | id from permissions table
--------------|---------------------------------------------
user_id       | int     | id from users table
--------------|---------------------------------------------
grant         | tinyint | 0 = deny, 1 = grant
```

Well, actually that's half of it, that part I am sure about, the part I am getting stuck on is the hierarchical roles.

So, how do I design this?
My idea is that to save on the database queries I am just going to build the permission matrix on login and save it to session so the queries don't have to be too simple as they are only run once for each login.

The issue I see is that, I am going to need to know the hierarchy of the roles so I can resolve the inherited roles permissions before I resolve the inheriting.

The user permissions is the easy part, the per-user permissions are essentially the finally resolved group.

Comment: Is there a reason why `user` have no `role`, but have `permission`? It's a "permisson model", not "role model", isn't it? With this approach, roles are not used anywhere.

Comment: Whoops, Forgot to add that table in, edited!

Comment: Still, I think there is no reason for `user` to have `permission`. It might have `role`s with `permission`s, but not `permission`s as they are. This thing ruining logic (IMHO).

Comment: @CORRUPT, A user themselves can also be given permissions, these permissions override any roles they are in. It saves having to create whole new roles with one permission just because you want User X to be able to do one extra action. Or if the user has been doing something they shouldn't you can quickly deny it for that user. Otherwise you would have to inherit the highest level role and then deny there which can get messy.

Comment: It's pretty much like saying that each user is their own role that automatically inherits from every other role the user has been given without actually having to create a group for the user. Does that make sense?

Comment: Tweaking the requirements such that records never deny, only additively grant permissions will simplify everything - forces better modelling of role hierarchy, especially the most restricted role, and simplifies permission lookup query (to an EXISTS). Denying everything by default and building on that is a [recommended approach](https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There is a way to implement role inheritance by using recursive relation on table `Roles`, by making role reference to another record:

[image: 1:n inheritance]

This relation will add `1 : n` inheritance within `Roles` record. You might obtain whole hierarchy tree with this stored function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `getHierarchy`(`aRole` BIGINT UNSIGNED)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE `aResult` VARCHAR(1024) DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE `aParent` BIGINT UNSIGNED;

SET `aParent` = (SELECT `parent` FROM `Roles` WHERE `id` = `aRole`);

WHILE NOT `aParent` IS NULL DO

    SET `aResult` = CONCAT_WS(',', `aResult`, `aParent`);
    SET `aParent` = (SELECT `parent` FROM `Roles` WHERE `id` = `aParent`);

END WHILE;

RETURN IFNULL(`aResult`, '');
END
```

Then, you might obtain all *granted* permissions with something like this:

```
SELECT
    `permission_id`
FROM
    `Permission_Role`
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(`role_id`, `getHierarchy`({$role}))
    AND
    grant;
```

If it's not enough, then you might do another table for inheritance:

[image: n:m inheritance]

But, in this case, needed another hierarchy obtainment algorithm.

---

To resolve ***overriding***  issue you will have to get role permissions and user permissions. Then, write `user` permissions over `roles` permissions to `session`.

---

Also, I suggest to remove `grant` columns in `Permission_Role` and `Permission_User`. There is no need to ***map*** every permission for each of them. Just enough to use `EXISTS` queries: if there is a record, then permission granted, else - it's not. If you need to retrieve all permissions and statuses, you might use `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: This sounds good, I will look into it, I am definitely looking at having each role inheriting multiple other roles, so will have to work out the other algorithm, also wondering how to do it if we cannot create stored procedures? Point with grant or deny is not to list every permission, point for grant or deny is that If a role inherits another role, if the inherited role has been granted the permission, you can explicitly deny it in the inheriting role to deny the permission.

Comment: To the above comment, we can delete the record to deny the permission explicitly, isn't it?

Comment: @coretechie Yes. Or, you can set `grant` to `false`. Also note, that some time had passed since this answer and MySQL finally got recusive query support. It now may be more optimal to select data with recursion. No stored procedures are required for such logic as of now.

Comment: Has anybody implemented this? GitHub?

Comment: @ChefGladiator It was fine solution at the time, but these days MySQL [supports recursive queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-hierarchy-traversal). I would suggest to look there for more robust approach without stored procedure complications. Unsure about ready-to-use components. I guess some of them depends on target ecosystem (php, python, etc). Consider checking packages with RBAC functionality. There are plenty of them.